# CSS Transform and Transition Effect

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out a way to make my checkbox transform at 0% scale(0) to 90% scale(1.3) to scale(1) so it has an in and out effect. Problem is I've been trying to accomplish this for the past couple of hours and need some help. Here is my CSS.

```
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.check-sq:before {
  content: "\f096";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  width:1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

 :checked + .check-sq:before {
  content: "\f14a";
  color: #06a3e9;

  /* Where I am needing help */

  transform: scale(0) scale(1.3) scale(1);
  transition: 1s transform ;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: This is generator http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transition.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work.

```
:checked + .check-sq:before {    
  animation: nameyouranimation [duration] forwards;
}

@keyframes nameyouranimation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ashugeo... I've been so close to this code it's really unreal. LMAO! I really appreciate your help!